# How to add a new tag: rhumb-line

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

How do I add a new, or suggest, tag?
There should be one for "rhumb-line".
I already have a definition and description prepared.

I cannot believe that I cannot see how to do this!  I've provided definitions and descriptions before -- maybe only after someone else has added an empty one? I've searched for "How to add a new tag".

(I've also had to add some verbiage to the title and body, to meet some machine-assessed quality guidelines!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a reputation greater than 300 I think you should already be able to do this because that is the threshold recorded **[here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)** for that privilege.

All you do is type in the tag in the tags section of the question where you first want to use a new tag and then put a space after it and it is done.

At that point it becomes available to write a tag wiki and excerpt.